Ethernet adapter stuck at 100Mbps connection when it should have 1Gbps
I'm about to start ripping my hair out over this issue..
Currently experiencing a problem where my internet connection is unstable and I'm only able to download around 100Mbps when it's usually around 600Mbps. This PC has run perfectly in the past, but I recently had it in a shop for a CPU issue. I just fresh installed W10 Enterprise IoT LTSC 2021 on this machine.
More info / steps I've taken to troubleshoot so far:

Not a component limitation, I've had this PC working properly before.
Not the router, other devices connected to the same router aren't capped to 100Mbps
Not the ethernet cable, not only has this exact PC gotten the full ~600Mbps connection with this same ethernet cable, the PC I was using while this one was in the shop also got the correct speeds.
Motherboard is MPG X570 GAMING EDGE WIFI (MS-7C37), just now downloaded and installed the Win10 64 Realtek PCI-E Ethernet Drivers from MSI (build 10.68.815.2023). MSI site says the release date of the drivers is 2023-11-29, but the driver details in Device Manager say "8/15/2023". Version number is identical though.
Made sure my connection wasn't metered
I've turned the router off and back on while ethernet cable is disconnected from PC
In advanced settings, I've Disabled Advanced EEE, Energy-Efficient Ethernet, Green Ethernet, Power Saving Mode, set Speed & Duplex to Auto Negotiation
Unchecked "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power"
I've uninstalled the ethernet controller from device manager
I saw a Reddit thread stating that this is a known issue with this motherboard, and that it has to do with third-party software called "cFosSpeed" messing with my network. I can't seem to find any indication that I have this software installed on my machine.
Did the standard ipconfig reset and DNS flush in admin CMD

Every article I've found when searching my problem has simply suggested setting Speed & Duplex to auto, or mentioned cFosSpeed (which I can't even confirm I have). Is there any chance that this could be caused by some setting in BIOS or something? My OS/hardware knowledge is extremely limited. Please someone help me, I just want to relax and play some video games after my 12-hour warehouse shift :(
https://i.sstatic.net/HlurtiDO.png

Just cause a cable was ok once dosen't mean its ok now Also, I'd test with a linux livecd to confirm its not hardware, and I'd say that windows IOT is an unusual option for a desktop - was it running that when things were ok?

The cable was working literally 5 minutes before I booted this PC up after the OS install. It's not the cable.. But I guess I'll swap out to a different cat6 just to rule it out when I get a chance.
And yeah, this PC was running IOT before I had to swap to another one. And that PC was running the same OS as well.

"Was working" also doesn't mean it was okay then, either – plenty of cables (like my old headphones' cable) that are already broken but still work in some positions, or cables that are hanging on by a hair and work until they're moved. Or a sudden burst of outside interference + cables that are more susceptible to outside interference than others, especially if there are motors or such around. (At work we still have that one outdoor cable that works perfectly at 100M – until it rains, at which point it switches down to 10M.) So check the cable anyway.

Alright, so.. I've tested the cable on another device, and confirmed it's not the cable. Interestingly, I temporarily got my regular download speeds back when I swapped the ethernet cable back and forth to different ports on my router.. I've had my ISP check and update the firmware on our equipment (along with the usual unplug/reset troubleshooting you'd expect) and that didn't produce any changes.
Now today, after randomly trying to test my RAM sticks for issues, I seem to have my regular 1.0Gbps ethernet adapter speed back. It's been a couple hours and it persists through reboots..

It seems like my ethernet device now randomly fluctuates between a 100Mbps connection and a 1.0Gbps connection, and it isn't influenced by any of the steps I highlighted in the OP or my comments since then.. :(

New question here too -- Is there any way that an external issue (e.g., ISP-related stuff) could mess with the connection between my PC and router? I've been operating under the assumption that it must be an issue with my PC when my ethernet adapter is capped to 100Mbps, but if that can be affected by my ISP, or the way this is all wired outside for our entire building, that definitely opens up many new avenues to troubleshoot.
